# sonarqube-4.5 mysql db file ibdata1 does not decrease in size after using sonarqube delete option to remove several projects

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

I have used the individual project as well as bulk deletion options in SonarQube 4.5.7 to remove old projects from the MySql database.
After doing this the /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 data file does not get any smaller. It has continued to grow to well over a hundred gigabytes.
What can I do that will cause this file to shrink back down, but yet not cause a data problem for SonarQube 4.5.7?

Thanks in advance for your answers.
Doug

Answer (score 0):

The size of MySQL data files won't shrink. This is not related to SonarQube but to MySQL.

The only way to shrink data files is to recreate the database: export DB in dump file, drop DB, recreate DB, import dump file into new DB. It's obviously a requirement that before this operation you actually remove some data (which you've already done).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give this a try when the builds/analysis are in a quite time.

Comment: From what my DBA said, "It would free up space if `innodb_file_per_table` and been `ON` since the beginning, but since it has been off, all of the data has been going into `ibdata1` which never shrinks." I asked what would happen if I turned on that parameter now. His comment was "Just be aware that the old space in ibdata1 will not be freed, and the restored data will now be taking up space elsewhere, so you end up using twice the storage after doing that." Do you know of any way short of dumping the DB and starting over - losing all history - to recover from this?